# List of standard comments for review

Tags: support, comments

When reviewing questions by new users, I often find myself commenting roughly the same again and again.

In spirit of the [Repository of useful pro-forma comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments) I would like to collect a list of generic comments for quick copy & paste access, specifically for Magento.SE.

A standard comment that explains why a question might be off topic or should be improved is better than no comment.

---

#### From the meta thread linked above:

> To use, click "edit", and fetch the snippet's markdown source code.
>
> > **Note**: For these snippets to be easy to copy&paste, do not use the editor's linking method, but inline links, like so:
> >
> > ```
> > [This is a link](http://www.this.is.the.url)
> > ```
>
> [Magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) might help too:
>
> > ```
> > See [so].
> > ```

Even better for easy usage: add the comment as

```
source code for copy and paste
```

and as

> quote for preview

Answer (score 7):

## Context: No fit for Q&A

### Shopping List Questions

```
"Shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A
(see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) -
you'll get better results at the Magento forums (https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension)
or Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)
```

Preview:

> "Shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A
>   (see:
>   [Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad))
>   - you'll get better results at the Magento forums (http://community.magento.com) or Reddit
>   (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)

### Asking for Discussion

```
Open questions and discussions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A - you'll get better
results at the Magento forums (http://community.magento.com) or
Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)
```

Preview:

> Open questions and discussions are not a good fit for StackExchange
>   Q&A 
>   - you'll get better results at the Magento forums (http://community.magento.com) or Reddit
>   (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)

Answer (score 5):

## Context: Insufficient information

### Question contains attempted solution, but doesn't describe actual problem

```html
What is the **actual** problem you're trying to solve? (see [xyproblem.info](http://xyproblem.info/))
```

> What is the **actual** problem you're trying to solve? (see [xyproblem.info](http://xyproblem.info/))

### Question only contains an error message

```
Please don't just dump error messages in the question form. You should at least explain
when it happens and if you did any changes before. To debug errors, follow this guide:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store
```

> Please don't just dump error messages in the question form. You should
>   at least explain when it happens and if you did any changes before. To
>   debug errors, follow this guide:
>   [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

### Question contains code but does not explain what it does

```
If you post code, please explain what this code is supposed to be doing, what actually
happens and where you need help. You should not expect us to run the code in our head and
guess the problem.
```

> If you post code, please explain what this code is supposed to be
>   doing, what actually happens and where you need help. You should not
>   expect us to run the code in our head and guess the problem.

### CSS question with screenshot

```
Debugging CSS is hard and even harder without knowing the source. This is a task that can
best be done on site and not a good question for the StackExchange Q&A. However, if you want
to try your luck, a screenshot is not enough information to help you. Please provide as much
information as possible: Which theme are you using? Were there any modifications to the
theme? Did it work correctly before and if so, what has been changed (for example
installed extensions)?
```

> Debugging CSS is hard and even harder without knowing the source. This
>   is a task that can best be done on site and not a good question for
>   the StackExchange Q&A. However, if you want to try your luck, a
>   screenshot is not enough information to help you. Please provide as
>   much information as possible: Which theme are you using? Were there
>   any modifications to the theme? Did it work correctly before and if
>   so, what has been changed (for example installed extensions)?

### Frontend question with URL ("this is my site, X does not work, please help")

```
Debugging JS/CSS is a task that can
best be done on site and not a good question for the StackExchange Q&A. However, if you
want to try your luck, please provide as much information as possible: Which theme are you
using? Were there any modifications to the theme? Did it work correctly before and if so,
what has been changed (for example installed extensions)? Do not just drop a URL - this can
help to provide context but eventually you will fix your problem and the question remains
without value for future visitors.
```

> Debugging JS/CSS is a task that can best be done on site and not a
>   good question for the StackExchange Q&A. However, if you want to try
>   your luck, please provide as much information as possible: Which theme
>   are you using? Were there any modifications to the theme? Did it work
>   correctly before and if so, what has been changed (for example
>   installed extensions)? Do not just drop a URL - this can help to
>   provide context but eventually you will fix your problem and the
>   question remains without value for future visitors.

### "Error" question with URL (same as above but not frontend specific)

```
Please do not just drop a URL and say "it does not work" - this can help to
provide context but eventually you will fix your problem and the question
remains without value for future visitors. Explain what happens, add error
messages or screenshots to the post, and also add any information that
might be relevant (like Magento version, recent changes)
```

> Please do not just drop a URL and say "it does not work" - this can
>   help to provide context but eventually you will fix your problem and
>   the question remains without value for future visitors. Explain what
>   happens, add error messages or screenshots to the post, and also add
>   any information that might be relevant (like Magento version, recent
>   changes)

Comment: The "Question only contains an error message" refers to https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store which is for Magento 1 and is locked. Can we do anything about that? Or refer to some other question or article? What is your idea on this?

Answer (score 3):

### Context: First question w/ few information

```
Hi and welcome to Magento SE, feel free to check out this post on how to ask a question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . 
Please provide more information such as **missing info #1, missing info #2 and missing info #3** so we can help you fixing your problem.
```

> Hi and welcome to Magento SE, feel free to check out this post
>   on how to ask a question:
>   https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . Please provide more
>   information such as **missing info #1, missing info #2 and missing info #3** so we can help you fixing your problem.

Answer (score 3):

## Context: Too broad

### General too broad

(add example tutorials, blog posts, articles if you'd like)

> The question you are asking is too broad and it cannot be answered within the scope of this Q&A website. Please search for a tutorial on this topic and if you encounter more specific issues, feel free to ask them here, providing enough context.

### Asking to write a complete module with almost no information

(adjust as needed, e.g. "payment module")

```
Asking for a walkthrough to a complete module is a bit too much for the Q&A format of this
site. Besides that, with this vague information it's not even possible to give a good answer.
We simply don't know your requirements. I'd suggest you to try starting and if you hit a
wall, ask for help here and explain exactly what you try to do, why you are doing it and
what does not work / where you need help.
```

Preview:

> Asking for a walkthrough to a complete module is a bit too much for
>   the Q&A format of this site. Besides that, with this vague information
>   it's not even possible to give a good answer. We simply don't know
>   your requirements. I'd suggest you to try starting and if you hit a
>   concrete wall, ask for help here and explain exactly what you try to
>   do, why you are doing it and what does not work / where you need help.

Answer (score 2):

### Context: First answers, not following the guidelines

#### Link to blog or article

```
Welcome to Magento SE. If you post links in an answer, please make sure that the answer is
still valuable, if the link becomes dead at some time: For example, summarize the linked
article or quote the relevant parts. This is important because StackExchange aims to be a
knowledge database, not a support forum that helps one person right now. Future visitors
should still benefit from the questions and answers.
```

> Welcome to Magento SE. If you post links in an answer, please make
>   sure that the answer is still valuable, if the link becomes dead at
>   some time: For example, summarize the linked article or quote the
>   relevant parts. This is important because StackExchange aims to be a
>   knowledge database, not a support forum that helps one person right
>   now. Future visitors should still benefit from the questions and
>   answers.

#### Self-answered question with answer in question

```
Welcome to Magento SE. Please do not post answers as questions. You can however answer
your own question (it's even encouraged!), if you want to share a solution for a problem
where no question exists yet. Please rephrase the question so that it is an answerable
question and post your solution as an answer. Thanks!
```

> Welcome to Magento SE. Please do not post answers as questions. You
>   can however answer your own question (it's even encouraged!), if you
>   want to share a solution for a problem where no question exists yet.
>   Please rephrase the question so that it is an answerable question and
>   post your solution as an answer. Thanks!

#### Only code in answer

```
Welcome to Magento SE. If you post code as an answer, please at least explain
briefly what this code is doing and where it belongs. Answers with code but no
explanation are rarely useful.
```

> Welcome to Magento SE. If you post code as an answer, please at least
>   explain briefly what this code is doing and where it belongs. Answers
>   with code but no explanation are rarely useful.

Answer (score 1):

### Context: Technically incorrect or problematic answers

This is for answers with **questionable advice**. Usually this does not mean that they should be flagged, but probably downvoted.

#### Delete `var/session` on a production site:

```
Deleting `var/session` on a production site is never an appropiate solution. See also:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94589/keeping-customers-logged-in-after-deleting-var-session
```

> Deleting `var/session` on a production site is never an appropiate
>   solution. See also:
>   [keeping customers logged in after deleting var/session in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94589/keeping-customers-logged-in-after-deleting-var-session)

#### Using `ObjectManager` directly:

```html
Using the `ObjectManager` directly is highly discouraged as it goes in against its design. You should use constructor dependency injection instead. See also:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly
```

> Using the `ObjectManager` directly is highly discouraged as it goes in against its design. You should use constructor dependency injection instead. See also:
>   [Magento 2: to use or not to use the ObjectManager directly?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly)

Answer (score 1):

### Context : Send Notification

When more than one user commented on OP's question, but the commenter did't tag a username when writing a comment, in that case, commented users don't get a notification.

```
If you want to notify the user, please [@tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/307988) their name in the comment.
```