# Too many questions with only requirement description and no code or a real issue

Tags: discussion, questions

From a time I am noticing questions which are only two or three lines explaining about "I want to ..." There is no code added in the question, there is nothing as a reference or anything.
Sometimes I feel like the questioner has tried nothing, they think like "Let me put it on stackexchange, let someone else do the work for me and I will only copy paste the solution"
Is there anything the community can do about such questions/users?

Comment: Flag the question and leave a comment is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 5):

If it's a question that could possibly be answered but there is no visible effort (as you described): **Downvote and move on**

If the "requirements" are not even clear: vote for closing, as "Unclear what you are asking"

If you are sure that an answer would require a disproportional amount of effort, you can also vote for closing as "Too broad", but be careful with that one, see: [Are "please write code for me" questions on topic here?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/955/are-please-write-code-for-me-questions-on-topic-here/956#956)

Comment: **Downvote and move on** : I think we cannot just move on after downvote. We need to add a comment

Comment: That's nice and I usually do it with new users but I don't agree that it's *needed*

Comment: ya. It's not a requirement, but better to have it. I just a pointed out that because you **emphasise** it in your answer :)

Comment: OK, fair enough :)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you should not downvote a question if this one is unclear. Our goal here is to educate people and be welcoming and thus getting a downvote straight after posting a question (specially for newcomers) will most likely make those new people run away.

If the question is unclear, try to clarify it by asking questions in the comments. On top of that, feel free to use the close and flag feature. It's not a big deal if a question is closed because it can be reopened later.

Also, feel free to use the awesome list of comments created by Fabian and the rest of the MSE community: [List of standard comments for review](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/970/2380)

Answer (score 0):

As Febian says if you find any question and think that this should not be here.

then simply flag that question with `should be closed` and give your reason , why this question `should be close`

and let community to decide whether this question belongs to here or not